# error[E0658]: `cfg(doctest)` is experimental and subject to change

Tags: rust, rust-piston

I am relatively new to rust and I was trying to build a game using an online tutorial when I encountered this error. Can someone please tell me what this error is and how to solve it?

I switched from stable rust version to nightly using `rustup default nightly` :- 
`rustc 1.46.0-nightly (feb3536eb 2020-06-09)`. still the error didn't go

These are the dependencies I am trying to install:

```
piston = "0.50.0"
piston2d-graphics = "0.36.0"
pistoncore-glutin_window = "0.64.0"
piston2d-opengl_graphics = "0.72.0"
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The error itself warns about the use of an unstable feature without having used the `feature` stanza which basically acknowledges that it could break at any moment, see [the error's documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0658). However `cfg(doctest)` should be stable since 1.40, I certainly get no warning on 1.44. Without a reproduction case I can't really help more than that.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Updating rust solves the error.

Answer (score 6):

Updating to the latest version of rust using `rustup update` solves the error